# web scrapping problem data exists but it show None

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, web, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.iplt20.com/stats/2023'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", class_="st-table statsTable ng-scope")
print(table)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMOJs.png)

I want to extract the table data which are available in this table but it show None.
Please help me to solve this problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhWyW.png)
```

this is web scraping task i want to extract the ipl stats data which is available in the mentioned class.

Comment: The table is dynamically rendered using JS. You cannot use the requests library to get the data, you need to get a headless browser (Selenium, Pupeeter, ...) or a rendering server (Splash, ...).

Answer (score 1):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via JavaScript. To load it into a pandas DataFrame you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://ipl-stats-sports-mechanic.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ipl/feeds/stats/107-toprunsscorers.js?callback=xxx'

data = requests.get(url).text.strip(';)')
data = json.loads(data.split('(', maxsplit=1)[-1])

df = pd.DataFrame(data['toprunsscorers'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               StrikerName PlayerId Matches   PlayerDOB RightHandedBat Nationality TCompetitionID                            TStrikerID TTeamID TeamCode                     TeamName CompetitionID TeamID                             StrikerID Innings Extras TotalRuns Balls Dotballs StrikeRate DBPercent DBFreq BdryFreq BdryPercent  RPSS ScoringBalls Ones Twos Threes Fours Sixes Outs NotOuts BattingAveragesss FiftyPlusRuns Centuries DoubleCenturies HighestScore BattingAverage Catches Stumpings ClientPlayerID
0             Shubman Gill       62      17  0000-00-00           true      Indian            107  2019-100mb00000000062-8fa4884a17f311      35       GT               Gujarat Titans           107     35  2019-100mb00000000062-8fa4884a17f311      17     33       890   564      150     157.80     26.59   3.76     4.77       60.44  2.14          414  244   48      4    85    33   15       2            445.00             4         3               0          129          59.33       6         0           3761
1           Faf Du Plessis       94      14  0000-00-00           true    Overseas            107  2019-100mb00000000094-1e8fa14543ee11      19      RCB  Royal Challengers Bangalore           107     19  2019-100mb00000000094-1e8fa14543ee11      14     21       730   475      133     153.68     28.00   3.57     4.94       62.46  2.13          342  219   26      1    60    36   13       1            730.00             8         0               0           84          56.15       3         0             24
2             Devon Conway      601      16  0000-00-00          false    Overseas            107  2021-100mb00000000601-517399b0ceaf11      13      CSK          Chennai Super Kings           107     13  2021-100mb00000000601-517399b0ceaf11      15     28       672   481      164     139.70     34.09   2.93     5.06       61.90  2.11          317  191   28      3    77    18   13       2            336.00             6         0               0          92*          51.69       6         0          20572
3              Virat Kohli        2      14  0000-00-00           true      Indian            107   2018-wicb00000000002-47ea5a6ae99a11      19      RCB  Royal Challengers Bangalore           107     19   2018-wicb00000000002-47ea5a6ae99a11      14     22       639   457      130     139.82     28.44   3.51     5.64       55.71  1.95          327  210   35      1    65    16   12       2            319.50             6         2               0         101*          53.25      13         0            164
4         Yashasvi Jaiswal      533      14  0000-00-00          false      Indian            107  2020-100mb00000000533-e895f279639811      18       RR             Rajasthan Royals           107     18  2020-100mb00000000533-e895f279639811      14     28       625   382      152     163.61     39.79   2.51     3.53       77.44  2.71          230  107   12      2    82    26   13       1            625.00             5         1               0          124          48.08       8         0          13538

...
```